# React-Bootstrap Modal With Component List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap` and opening a modal window that will provide a link list of usable components. What I'm trying to achieve is, when a link within the list is clicked, the modal contents will be replaced by the selected component. I've created the following CodePen to demonstrate what I'm wanting to do.

http://codepen.io/addam/pen/VpqOOg

My question is if this the "React" way to go about such a solution. It seems weird to me that I would need an array with the component stored in it. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: This looks clean to me! Waiting to see if someone has a suggestion!